# Error HH100: Network mumbai doesn't exist

Tags: hardhat, polygon

I am trying to deploy my first contract :) However I keep getting the same error message:

`Error HH100: Network mumbai doesn't exist`

Here is my config:

```
// hardhat.config.js
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.9",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    mumbai: {
      url: process.env.API_URL,
      accounts: [`0x${process.env.PRIVATE_KEY}`],
      chainId: 80001, // Add the chainId for Mumbai network
    },
  },
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.4",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Here is what I am running:

`npx hardhat run scripts/2_deploy_contracts.js --network mumbai`

Appreciate any help!

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. `npx hardhat clean`
2. restart after saving work
3. `npx hardhat run scripts/2_deploy_contracts.js --network mumbai`

Hope this helps anyone else with this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Check sure your .env file is in the root directory of your project and contains the correct API_URL and PRIVATE_KEY variables. You can print them out to make sure they are being correctly loaded. For example, add the following lines in your hardhat.config.js file:

```
console.log('API_URL:', process.env.API_URL);
console.log('PRIVATE_KEY:', process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);
```

Just make sure to remove or comment out these lines when you've confirmed that your environment variables are being loaded correctly.

If that's not what's causing the issue, try reinstalling Hardhat:

```
npm uninstall hardhat
npm install --save-dev hardhat
```

Good luck.

Comment: Tried both solutions and still it didn't work. Still says:

`Error HH100: Network mumbai doesn't exist`

I have also added this constant:

`const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;` to the hardhat.config. 

As well as reinstalling `install dotenv --save`, copied and pasted the api_url and private key from alchemy and Metamask (was definitely correct). I am definitely connected in Metamask, but I just can not connect to Mumbai from my project :(